# Webpack multiple bundle based on configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, bundle

I've worked with Webpack a little. I know who to do multiple bundles depends on multiple entry points, but I have a new situation.

One of our projects has a single codebase for 3 different countries *(3 different URL and different URL structure)*. We have set of common codes and codes for C1, C2, C3. I want to run a single build and compile the ES6 code in 2 different files, like

`app-common.js`, `c1-common.js`, `c2-common.js`, `c3-common.j2`

Or

`c1-app.js`, `c2-app.js`, `c3-app.js` which will have common and specific js code baesd on configuration, like which files I want to bind with which bundle.

Is there any existing way to do it or how this can be achieved?

Comment: have you tried `CommonsChunkPlugin` https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/ or `dllPlugin`? try reading this https://robertknight.github.io/posts/webpack-dll-plugins/

Answer (score 2):

You could create a single point-of-entry file for your localized code and do conditional `require` statements based on a custom environment variable. Then set that up in your webpack config:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.COUNTRY_CODE': 'fr'
}),
```

Then in your code:

```
let i18n_config;
const country = process.env.COUNTRY_CODE || 'en';

if (country === 'en') {
    i18n_config = require("./i18n/en.js");
}
if (country === 'fr') {
    i18n_config = require("./i18n/fr.js");
}
```

You can go even further and use an aggressive minifier to remove dead code:

```
const isEN = country === 'en';
const isFR = country === 'fr';

if (isEN) {
    i18n_config = require("./i18n/en.js");
}
if (isFR) {
    i18n_config = require("./i18n/fr.js");
}
// ... and so on
```

Your `if` statements will compile to `if (true) {...}` or `if (false) {...}`. The `false` block will be considered dead-code and will be removed by the minifier.

Comment: Will try it tonight.